# Handlebars express css file not loading

Tags: css, templates, handlebars.js, static-libraries, express-handlebars

I've looked at some of the similar questions on stack overflow but nothing seems to be working for me. Can someone help?

I have tried changing the path in the main.handlebars page and at some point it worked for a moment, but I am not sure what I changed that stopped it from working.

I have made sure I have installed all the relevant npms and referenced them. I've tried re-arranging where in the server.js file that I reference the static folder.

The console error says: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/assets/css/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I've tried specifying the css file as a type="text/css", but that didn't change anything.

Here is my main.handlebars page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>ADORE - Animals Deserving of Rescue Everywhere</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|IBM+Plex+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--Custom CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/index.css"/>

</head>

<body id="newBackground">
        <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg static-top"  id="navbar-color">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand navtext-color" href="">ADORE - Animals </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <div class="dropdown show">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle nav-link navtext-color" role="button" href="about/about.html" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/mission">Mission Statement</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/board">Board Members</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navtext-color" href="/adopt">Adopt</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navtext-color" href="/foster">Foster</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navtext-color" href="/events">Events</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navtext-color" href="/volunteer">Volunteer</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navtext-color" href="/resources">Resources</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navtext-color" href="/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
    {{{ body }}}
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.7/handlebars.js" integrity="sha256-3kxM38zABJY692X6ViIlt9FsBimhck0ZlsLtuA7R+0Y=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

here is my server.js page:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require('dotenv').config();
var path=require('path');
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const axios = require('axios');

// Specify the port.
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Create an instance of the express app.
var app = express();
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


// Set Handlebars as the default templating engine.
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

var routes = require("./controllers/routes.js");

app.use(routes);


app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("App now listening at localhost:" + PORT);
  });
```

my routes.js:

```
var express = require("express");

var router = express.Router();
const board = require("../board.js");

router.get("/mission", function(req, res) {
    console.log("something happened");
    res.render("mission");
  });

router.get("/board", function(req,res){
    console.log("here is more");
    res.render("board", board);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my file structure:

[an image of my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZspR.png)

Comment: Alright, so I solved this after posting this question by watching this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lRgL9kj_h0. I hope that it helps whoever else might come across this. Essentially I needed to reference the public folder in my main.handlebars doc.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue and this helped a lot!!